# Outputting HTML-encoded tags as HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some text from a service that looks like this:

```
Text with some &lt;p%gt; tags.
```

If I output that in Rails with `.html_safe` it renders like this:

```
Text with some <p> tags.
```

but I want the tags to actually be HTML, so it would render like this:

```
Text with some

tags.
```

or similar.

I can't seem to work out how to get Rails to decode the entities *and* output them as HTML - I've tried various combinations of `.html_safe` and `CGI.unencode` but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: cant you call html_safe twice on your string?

Comment: @Ben No, html_safe only tells Rails not to encode the string. The string is already encoded, so telling it not to encode it twice doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, 30 seconds after I posted this I worked out a solution:

```
CGI.unescapeHTML(string).html_safe
```

does it :)